# Avalonia exception "Unable to find view for <class name>"

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, avaloniaui

I have a VS solution with the following projects so that I can share UI code between iOS and Windows:

- MyApp.UI.Avalonia - a .NET Standard Class Library with Avalonia nuget package

  - contains XAML/CS files for UI
- MyApp.iOS - a Xamarin iOS project, with Avalonia and Avalonia.iOS nuget packages

  - Depends on
- MyApp.Windows - a Windows Application project created from the Avalonia project template (with XAML files deleted)

When I run the Windows application, I get an exception in my App class at the call to AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this): `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Unable to find view for MyApp.App`

It looks like it is failing when trying to find App.xaml, the corresponding XAML file to the App.cs file. It does so by looking for resource with URL something like "avares:/!AvaloniaResourceXamlInfo". When I debug this process in the Avalonia solution's ControlCatalog project, it does find a resource by this name in the shared ControlCatalog class library assembly, and inside that resource it finds all of the XAML files and Assets.

A difference I notice between my project and theirs is that when I right click the project and select Add -> Item -> User Control (Avalonia), it creates a XAML file wrapping a CS file in their project, but in my project it creates the two files merely side-by-side. What project setup am I missing to get the XAML files into this magical "!AvaloniaResourceXamlInfo" resource?

**Update:**
While I still get the same error, I was able to get the xaml.cs files to encapsulate the corresponding .cs files (so apparently that isn't the only issue) by adding the following to my .csproj file manually (which I found in the ControlCatalog sample project):

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="**\*.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>%(Filename)</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <AvaloniaResource Include="**\*.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AvaloniaResource>
    <AvaloniaResource Include="Assets\*" />
    <AvaloniaResource Include="Assets\Fonts\*" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the property of the file?

[image: csproj file]

Comment: You mean in the .csproj file? Does the XML you shared go in the csproj somewhere, and the solution is to manually edit it? Could you please edit your answer to include more detail?

Comment: yes within the .csproj file,Did you try making the app.xaml file a Compile or a embedded resource.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to align Namespaces with paths in this project.

Avalonia seems to be a bit picky about it.

Despite .Net allows Namespaces and paths to be something different

Answer (score -1):

The project ran without error once I manually added the following to the .csproj file of the .NET Standard library project shared by the Windows and iOS application projects:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="**\*.xaml.cs">
        <DependentUpon>%(Filename)</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="**\*.xaml">
        <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <AvaloniaResource Include="**\*.xaml">
        <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AvaloniaResource>
    <AvaloniaResource Include="Assets\*" />
    <AvaloniaResource Include="Assets\Fonts\*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Looks like that `<Compile ...` tag encapsulates the cs filese into the xaml.cs files, and the rest embeds the xaml files as resources which can be found by Avalonia.